# how can write the code in edit changed event of the column of the html table

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-core

I am trying to write the script in javascript while we change the value in any column either the column  'HolidayHrs' , or the column 'TimeOffHrs' . While we editchanged  in either of the column I have to show some message in javascript. Here is my script

```js
<script>
// after edit  of the column HolidayHrs or TimeOffHrs  I have to print console.log("Edited") 
</script>
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none !important;
}
```

```html
<table id="attendance" class="cell-border" style="width:100%">
<tbody>
 for (i = 0; i < Model.attendanceLogList.Count; i++)
{
  <tr id="@i"
     <td><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsProtected" type="hidden" /><input type="checkbox" value="true" disabled asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsNormalAttendance" data-tag="NormalHrs" /> <input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsNormalAttendance" /><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsClockingEnabled" type="hidden" /> </td>
    <td><a href="#" data-pk="NormalHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs</a><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].NormalHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" /></td>


    <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsHolidayMarked" data-tag="HolidayHrs" /><input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsHolidayMarked" /> </td>
    <td><a href="#" data-pk="HolidayHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs</a><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].HolidayHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" /></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" value="true" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsTimeOff" data-tag="TimeOffHrs" /><input type="hidden" value="false" asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].IsTimeOff" /> </td>
    <td><a href="#" data-pk="TimeOffHrs">@Model.attendanceLogList[i].TimeOffHrs</a><input asp-for="@Model.attendanceLogList[i].TimeOffHrs" type="hidden" class="bros" /></td>

  </tr>
}
</tbody>
</table>
<script>
```

Comment: Listen `change` event on `table`. In the listener, `event.target.parentElement.cellIndex` is `3` for `HolidayHrs`, and `5` for `TimeOffHrs`. Check the index, and if it matches to those values, then an input of the specific column was changed.

Comment: Hmm ... actually if the index matches to `2` or `4`, as the odd-ones seem to be hidden.